# Google Apps - Email Storage Amount - Special Number?

Tags: google-apps, quota

http://www.google.com/apps/

> 25GB email storage per user

but in the footnote it says:

> 7.527493 GB of email storage per account

It seems a bit precise. What's special about that number that I'm not seeing?

I thought maybe it's a phone number (752-749-3000) but no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not special, it's increasing every second or so by a few Bytes or so.

Go to https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=mail and see how it increases.

Answer (score 0):

> What's special about that number that I'm not seeing?

7.527493 is 2.39607544 * pi.

That new magic number, BTW, is 0.8814668939 * e.

And that magic number is 1.33e+33 times Planck's constant in Joule-seconds.

I think that's what you might be missing.